# I am not able to install gatsby

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby

[image]

List item

```
C:\Users\admin>npm install -g gatsby-cli
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"name":"@babel/cod'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-21T09_15_09_544Z-debug.log

C:\Users\admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below command

```
$ npm cache verify

$ npm cache clean --force
```

and then try again.

If you still get the error then use yarn package manager. Install yarn by running this

```
$  npm install -g yarn
```

and then configure angular cli to use the yarn package manager, by running this command

```
$ ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```